# youtube-dl downloading in .bin format instead of mp4

Tags: download, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download list of videos from a website with youtube-dl. I'm getting the video in a .bin format instead of .mp4. Below is the code for the donwload and also I included the screenshot for the downloaded file.Thanks in advance for your help. :)

```
sudo youtube-dl --cookies zerotomastery.io_cookies.txt -o \ "~/courses/%(chapter_number)s-%(chapter)s/%(autonumber)03d-%(title)s.%(ext)s" \ https://academy.zerotomastery.io/courses/enrolled/776308
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out myself in the docs. I have to use the --recode-video option then followed by "bin>mp4"

Answer (score 0):

You can re-encode the video as the below answer states, but since the file you are downloading is probably already an mp4 file (and youtube-dl just doesn't know that), you can usually simply rename the file to have the suffix .mp4 instead of .bin. If the file is already an mp4 (they usually are), this should work.

If it doesn't, use the following command:

```
youtube-dl --recode-video mp4 https://video_link_here
```

Note that in order to re-encode the video you will have to have encoding software like ffmpeg or avconv installed. If you don't, youtube-dl will ask you to install one of these.